# I'm lost, where do I go from here?

Tags: java

My teacher asked that we use the ASCII characters from 33 to 127 to generate a password that is n length.  I got lost and am not sure where to go from here.  This is what I have so far:

```
 import java.util.*;
  public class PasswordGenerator {
   public static void main(String[]args){
     Random random = new Random();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter password length: ");
     int length = input.nextInt();
     StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(length);
     int count = random.nextInt(127-33+1)-33'
      if(length<0) {
        System.out.println(Invalid password length: "+length);
       }
       else {
       for(int i = 33; i<126+1; i++) {
```

Comment: Please complete the code and fix any errors that would keep it from compiling like - `int count = random.nextInt(127-33+1)-33'`.

Comment: you did not end your int count statement

Comment: The `for` loop should be iterating `length` times. For each iteration, you need a random number 33-127, so the call should be `random.nextInt(127-33+1) + 33` (notice the `+ 33`, not `- 33`).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `Random` object correctly, since as it is, you can generate negative numbers.

This is one way to implement what you are describing:

```
if(length<0) /*handle error*/;
StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
    password.append((char) (random.nextInt(127-33+1)+33));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);){
        System.out.print("Enter password length: ");
        int length = input.nextInt();
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
        if (length < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid password length: " + length);
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
            password.append((char) (random.nextInt(127-33) + 33));
        }
        System.out.println(password.toString());
    }
}
```

changes:

- Count variable was not needed.
- Length was not being utilized.
- Scanner object was not closed, causing a resource leak.

Comment: it should be nextInt(127-33+1), otherwise you could never generate 127

Comment: @Maljam That's arguably a feature. ASCII 127 is not a printable character.

Comment: ok I want to thank you for your help.  I have utilized your suggestions but now the password being generated is repeating letters/symbols and is not the wanted length.

Comment: Do you have any example?